# Material ui onClose as replacement for disableBackdropClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog

Currently I have a dialog

```
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    data-testid="myTestDialog"
    disableEscapeKeyDown={true}
    disableBackdropClick={true}
  >
```

From the docs https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/ disableBackdropClick is depreciated and onClose should be used instead but how can I modify the above code to make it work using the new onClose, I am not familiar with this function/signature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use onClose, your variable *open* needs to be settable. When *open* is true the dialog is shown and when onClose is called it sets *open* to false but only when it is not closing because of a background click or escape press.

E.g.

```
<Dialog
    open={open}
    data-testid="myTestDialog"
    onClose={(event, reason) => {
        if(reason !== 'backdropClick' && reason !== 'escapeKeyDown') {
            // Set 'open' to false, however you would do that with your particular code.
            setOpen(false);
        }
    }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar issue when [migrating from MUI 4 to MUI 5](https://dev.to/teaganga/handle-dialogdisablebackdropclick-descoped-property-warning-in-mui-v5-2i35). I've fixed this way:

```
      <Dialog
        open={showModal}
        disableBackdropClick
        disableEscapeKeyDown
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        onClose={handleDlgClose}
      >
      ...
```

```
  const handleDlgClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason && reason == "backdropClick") {
      console.log('backdropClicked. Not closing dialog.')
      return;
    }

    setShowModal(false);
  }
```